# Python file reading results in twice as many lines?

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to read a file using Python, where I want to separate the last column. But apparently, according to `len(data)` and `len(labels)`, for each iteration, two elements are added to both `data` and `labels`. The file itself contains regular `\n` newlines and does not contain any other non-printable characters.

```py
def read_data(filename):
    print 'Start reading \"' + filename + '\"..'
    f = open(filename)
    data = labels = []
    for line in f:
            line = line.strip().split(',')
            labels.append(int(float(line[-1])))
            data.append([int(x) for x in (line[:-1])])
    f.close()
    print 'Finished reading.'
    return data, labels
```

I'm sort of stuck here and some debugging has not been fruitful for quite some time. Any ideas?

Comment: can u show some sample input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = labels = []
```

This creates one list, and when you do `labels.append(...)` and `data.append(...)` you append to the same list.

You should do:

```
data = []
labels = []
```

Comment: data, labels = [], []

Comment: Thanks! I assume this is like two variables referring to the same object, which happens for non-primitive types. I didn't know it worked like this in Python.

Comment: It's a very important concept in Python. Google for "immutable mutable objects python"